# gdal_translate is not working apache user

Tags: php, linux, apache, gdal, geoserver

When I call command in **ssh** console `root user` its all working, but I call in program in `apache user` this not working, please help

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" /opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/11-38-137-\
  (109-3\)\.tif  /opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/all/TCSHAPE.tif
```

Comment: This is because the `root` user and `apache` user use different environments. How is the command *"not working"* when you run it as `apache` user? Do you get an error message in the output or in a log file? What error message?

Comment: command is 
`gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" /opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/11-38-137-\(109-3\)\.tif  /opt/path/path/TCSHAPE/all/TCSHAPE.tif`
error is not returned, returned null